# Can we use custom JSON Data on Cubism?

Tags: json, d3.js, cubism.js

I saw the cubism graphs and they are simply amazing. I have a big JSON file with 1000 entries that have a timestamp and a value (integer). Can Cubism graph those or not?! I can't seem to find documentation on this...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cubism is generally intended for realtime data, but you can implement a metric that simply returns static values from a JSON file. Typically you do this by using [context.metric](https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Context#wiki-metric). See the [stocks demo](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/cubism/intro/demo-stocks.html) in the [Cubism intro talk](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/cubism/intro/) for an example.

Comment: Perfect thanks! These links should be put on the Cubism website!!