# simple cubism.js with json datasource

Tags: d3.js, cubism.js

I'm looking for a way to use json datasource in cubism.js
here is my code:

```
<script>
var context = cubism.context()
    .serverDelay(0)
    .clientDelay(0)
    .step(1e3)
    .size(960);


var dataset = [ [-1, -3], [2, 4], [3, -4], [-3, 1]];
//var foo = random("foo");
var foo = context.metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {
  d3.json(dataset, function(data) {
    if (!data) return callback(new Error("unable to load data"));
    callback(null, data);
  });
});
var bar = random("bar");

d3.select("#kpi2").call(function(div) {

  div.append("div")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(context.axis().orient("top"));

  div.selectAll(".horizon")
      .data([foo])
    .enter().append("div")
      .attr("class", "horizon")
      .call(context.horizon().extent([-20, 20]));

  div.append("div")
      .attr("class", "rule")
      .call(context.rule());

});

context.on("focus", function(i) {
  d3.selectAll(".value").style("right", i == null ? null : context.size() - i + "px");
});

</script>
```

I heard about using context.metric but i don't know how to use,coz im a newbie in this area.
thanks

Comment: Have you checked out this link?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526058/using-other-data-sources-for-cubism-js?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

```
    function stock(name) { 
    return context.metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {
        d3.json("/data" + name + ".json", function(rows) {
            var compare = rows[0][1], value = rows[0][1], values = [value];

            // Creates an array of the price differences throughout the day
            rows.forEach(function(d) {
                values.push(value = (d[1] - compare) / compare);
            }); 
        callback(null, values); }); 
    }, name); 
}
```

You can check out this example for more details: http://www.kshitijaranke.com/author/

or

[Can we use custom JSON Data on Cubism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747433/can-we-use-custom-json-data-on-cubism)

It should give you a head start on how to do it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You mean I'm suppose to add in a code snippet to indicate as an answer and state that I reference for the link above right?